# plotting ilaplace output MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

I'm trying to plot the transfer function in time domain - h,
when I run the following code I get an error:

```
syms s;
H=((1+2*s)*1.943)/(s*(s^2)*(1+0.15*s)+((1+2*s)*1.943));

h = ilaplace(H);
ezplot(h);
```

I read the help on ilaplace and understood it returns a sym function.
what am I missing?

I tried to look up on the internet and I didn't find an example that perform what I want without errors.

if it is relevant I'm using 7.12.0 (R2011a)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the expression for `h`, I bet you'll find it's not a straightforward expression of `t`, and it's not something that can be plotted by MATLAB due to the complexity of the equation. You might want to try substituting some numerical values of `t` with [`subs`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to get the corresponding values of `h`, which you could then plot using the `plot` command, but I don't know if this will work owing to the complexity of the inverse Laplace transform expression.